# How to make paragraph start title in IEEE trans

Tags: fonts, paragraphs, ieeetran

using the IEEE trans format, how to display the paragragh title such as "Relaxing the Autonomy condition" as shown below?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One possibility would be to redefine one of the existing sectional units, `\paragraph` for example, to produce the desired layout; this implies also a redefinition of `\@IEEEsectpunct` (punctuation after running headings) from the default colon to a period:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\def\@IEEEsectpunct{.\ \,}
\def\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}{1.5ex plus 1.5ex minus 0.5ex}%
{0ex}{\normalfont\normalsize\sffamily\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[4]
\paragraph*{Relaxing the autonomy condition}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}​
```

[image]

If you don't want to redefine sectional units and this is only to be used one time, you can also simply produce the formatting manually using `\medskip` to add some extra vertical space, `\noindent` to suppress the indentation and `\textbf` to change to boldfaced font:

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}

\begin{document}
some test text  test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text
\par\smallskip

\noindent\textbf{Relaxing the Autonomy Condition.}
some test text  test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text

\end{document}
```

[image]